# Macro to remove boilerplate from Compojure routes

Tags: clojure, macros, compojure

I'd like to some remove boilerplate from my Compojure routes by introducing a macro but can't seem to get it work.

I have the following context block that repeats (for a bunch of database tables) in my route spec like so:

```
(defroutes app-routes 
    (context "/foo" []
        (GET "/a" [] "a")
        (GET "/a/1" [] "a/1")
        (GET "/b" [] "b"))

    (context "/bar" []
        (GET "/a" [] "a")
        (GET "/a/1" [] "a/1")
        (GET "/b" [] "b"))
    ...
```

which I've tried to encapsulate using a macro (or a fn) so I'd end up using it like so:

```
(defroutes app-routes
  (app "foo" {:a true :b false}
    (GET "/x" [] "x"))
  (app "bar" {:a false :b true}
    (GET "/x" [] "x"))
    ...
```

where the second argument controls which routes are added, and the third a bunch of other routes that may be specific to this base route.

I have this so far and it doesn't seem to work as `routes` seems to fail on nulls introduced by my attempt to write the said macro.

```
(defmacro app [title flags data & routes]
`(context ~(str "/" title) []
    (GET "/" [:as req#] "index")
    (GET "/:id/edit" [id# :as req#] "edit")
    (POST "/:id/edit" [id# :as req#] "edit")

    ~(when (:a flags)
        `(GET "/:id/a" [id# :as req#] "a")
        `(GET "/:id/a/1" [id# :as req#] "a"))

    ~(when (:b flags)
        `(GET "/:id/b" [id# :as req#] "b")
        `(GET "/:id/b/1" [id# :as req#] "b"))

    (routes ~@routes)))
```

Any help on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does this macro successfully expand? Like `(macroexpand '(app whatever))`

Comment: @D-side: Yes it expands but `when` a block is false, it's replaced with a null which results in a NPE (in the routes call in Compojure). Also, I realized only the last route in the `when` makes it when the block is true so I had to replace them with individual if blocks like so: ```~(if (:a flags) `(GET "/:id/a" [] "here") `(GET "/404" [] "nf"))```. And that seems to fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Write that as an answer then :)